# my resizable background is not working after adding frame on the canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am beginner in tkinter. I have added a resizable background which is perfectly working. Have look to the code
'''

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

homeWin = tk.Tk()
homeWin.geometry("400x400")
background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "bg.png")
hw_canvas = tk.Canvas(homeWin, width = 400, height=400)
hw_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
bg = hw_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = background, anchor = "nw")

def bg_resizable(e):
    global image, resized, image2
    # open image to resize it
    image = Image.open("bg.png")
    # resize the image with width and height of root
    resized = image.resize((e.width, e.height), Image.LANCZOS)
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    hw_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image2, anchor='nw')

homeWin.bind("<Configure>", bg_resizable)
homeWin.mainloop()
```

'''
but after placing a frame on the canvas it is not working.
I don't know why this is. Pleas help me with it!
'''

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

homeWin = tk.Tk()
homeWin.geometry("400x400")
background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "bg.png")
hw_canvas = tk.Canvas(homeWin, width = 400, height=400)
hw_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
bg = hw_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = background, anchor = "nw")

def bg_resizable(e):
    global image, resized, image2
    # open image to resize it
    image = Image.open("bg.png")
    # resize the image with width and height of root
    resized = image.resize((e.width, e.height), Image.LANCZOS)
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    hw_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image2, anchor='nw')

homeWin.bind("<Configure>", bg_resizable)

sl_frame = tk.Frame(hw_canvas, bg="white", width= 200, height=500)
sl_frame.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.5, anchor="center")

homeWin.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Since you bind `<Configure>` on `homeWin` (root window), the binding will be inherited by its children and children of children.  So if the last trigger widget is the frame, then the image will be resized to the size of the frame.  You should bind the event on `hw_canvas` instead.  Also you should not create new canvas image item inside the event callback.  Use `hw_canvas.itemconfigure(bg, image=image2)` instead of `hw_canvas.create_image(...)` inside the event callback.

Comment: Thanks alot!! this works for me very well. But can you tell me what is bg in ''hw_canvas.itemconfigure(bg, image=image2)''. Please refer me something so that i can explore more about itemconfigure method. Once again thank you

Comment: `bg` is the item ID returned by `hw_canvas.create_image(...)` on the line `bg = hw_canvas.create_image(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"<Configure>"` events get called for main window and all children!

Using the following can exclude child `"<Configure>"` events:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def bg_resizable(e):
    global image, resized, image2
    # main window has no master
    if e.widget.master:
        return
    # resize the image with width and height of root
    resized = image.resize((e.width, e.height), Image.LANCZOS)
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    hw_canvas.itemconfigure(bg, image=image2)

image = Image.open("bg.png") # open image once, global

homeWin = tk.Tk()
homeWin.geometry("400x400")

hw_canvas = tk.Canvas(homeWin, width = 400, height=400)
hw_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
bg = hw_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw')

sl_frame = tk.Frame(hw_canvas, bg="white", width= 200, height=500)
sl_frame.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.5, anchor="center")

homeWin.bind("<Configure>", bg_resizable)
homeWin.mainloop()
```

Also, note because event fires when window is first shown, there is not need to handle background outside of event.

Comment: @acw1668's comment seem more efficient - binding to the canvas.